# Finding the number of experiments given the probability

Tags: probability

How many experiments should we conduct so that we could state that with more than $0.9$ probability the event occurs at least once. The probability that the event occurs is $0.7$.

I have tried the following:

Let's say the number of experiments is equal to $n$. 
The opposite of 'occurs at least once' is that the event occurs in **all** experiments and the probability of this be $1-0.9=0.1.$

So I need the following $(0.7)^n=0.1$

Solving this does not give me the right answer, which is **more than $2$**.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the random variable $X=$ the number that the event occurs (i.e. the number of successes) which is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ (which is unknown and which we want to estimate) and $p=0.7$. So, we know that $P(X=k)=\dbinom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$. Moreover $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}P(X=k)=1$$ We want to determine $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$P(X \geq 1)\geq 0.9$$ As is it is already mentioned we can solve the above relation as follows $$\begin{align*} 0.9 \leq P(X \geq 1)&= 1-P(X<1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\dbinom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^n=\\&=1-1\cdot1\cdot(1-0.7)^n=1-0.3^n \end{align*}$$ which gives $$0.3^n \leq 0.1$$ or equivalently by applying $\ln$ in both sides $$n\geq1.91$$ which means that at least $n=2$ experiments should be conducted so that there is at least $0.9$ probability that the event occurs at least once.

So the right answer is not more than $2$, but $2$ or more.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of "occurs at least once" is not "always occurs" -- it is "never occurs".  (Think about it this way: if $N$ is the number of times the event occurs, then the negation of "$N\geq 1$" is "$N\leq 0$".  Since $N\geq0$ by definition, $N\leq0$ is equivalent to $N=0$.)